# Place two A5 pages on A4 using memoir

Tags: memoir, printing

I was trying ConTeXt out and found out about [imposition](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition). I'm specifically interested in the 2UP schema, so I can just print on a regular A4 and trim.

I have a book typeset using LaTeX and `memoir`. Then I took a look at `memman.pdf`, to try to find information about how this could be accomplished. I tried using `a4paper` and `landscape` class option, then `\pageav`, but that just got me a A4 sheet with a A5 page inside it.

How can it be done? I read something about `pdfpages` but didn't try it just yet, because I think there is a native way of doing so using `memoir`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think just memoir can do this.  I like to do this with pgfpages (part of pgf/tikz), the border shrink command is especially useful.  Sample from the pgf manual:

```
\usepackage{pgfpages} 
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,landscape,border shrink=5mm]
```

Comment: Note: there is some trickiness with page numbers, meaning you will need to compile without pgfpages, and recompile with pgf pages with in addition the line "\nofiles".  This ensures that the .aux has the right page numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from doing it in TeX directly, you could generate the PDF in A4 and then print it as an A5 booklet.

Acrobat Reader has an option to print A4 documents as a booklet. You can also use the following bash script to convert an A4 PDF file into an A5 booklet:

```
#!/bin/bash

BOOK_PDF="$1"
NAME=$(basename $BOOK_PDF .pdf)

echo "NAME is $NAME"

TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
BOOK_PS=$TMPDIR/$NAME.ps
BOOKLET_TMP_PS=$TMPDIR/$NAME.booklet.tmp.ps
BOOKLET_PS=$TMPDIR/$NAME.booklet.ps
BOOKLET_PDF=$NAME.booklet.pdf


pdftops $BOOK_PDF $BOOK_PS
psbook $BOOK_PS $BOOKLET_TMP_PS
pstops "4:0L@.7(21cm,0)+1L@.7(21cm,14.85cm),2R@.7(0,29.7cm)+3R@.7(0,14.85cm)" \
   $BOOKLET_TMP_PS > $BOOKLET_PS

ps2pdf $BOOKLET_PS $BOOKLET_PDF
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. The perfect solution, however, would be using `pdfpages`. I feel like it is easier to use — and I actually don't want to print the whole book, just a few pages.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know memoir does not support this, I would go with pdfpages.

If you got the impression from the manual, please let me know from where, such that I can change it.

Comment: I just assumed that `memoir` could do it. Is it hard to do that using `pdfpages`?