# Booklets in memoir class

Tags: memoir, book-design, printing

I was just reading this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16803/place-two-a5-pages-on-a4-using-memoir) about using pdfpages to create twoup effects in memoir.  This worked great for me, but I am wondering how I can get the page order to set up a booklet, so that it can be folded in half with correct pagination.  I never got the booklet code to work.  Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package provides an easy way to arrange the pages of a `PDF` file so that it can be printed as a booklet. For two A5 pages arranged on an A4 landscape paper, the correct choice of options is

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,booklet,landscape]{document.pdf}
\end{document}
```

More information, e.g. on splitting the booklet into several signatures, can be found in the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf).

Comment: It didn't work the first few times I tried, and of course I set this up in a new tex file, but it worked like a charm.  THank you!

Answer (score 1):

say it is 4 pages, then the order would be (duplex on short edge I think)

2 3 4 1

so

```
\includepdf[pages={2,3,4,1},...]{file.pdf}
```

(or similar)

Comment: So that is just a code to custom order the pages, after I do the laying out?  I was hoping there was something that could do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want 4 on 1 layout with a booklet orientation, you can use pgfpages like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
% TEX.SE \url{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}


\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{4 on 1 booklet}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperheight} 
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperwidth}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=4,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    rotation=180,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    rotation=180,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}
  {%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1 booklet}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

There is a [bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16237/is-there-a-way-to-rotate-all-pages-in-xelatex/16245#16245) in pgfpages with rotation that needs to be fixed first, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`booklet`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booklet/) package.

Comment: I did.  no good.