# Booklet with a specific page order rule

Tags: book-design

Friends, consider the following example (**mytext.tex**):

```
\documentclass[a5paper,oneside,12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

{\Huge A}

\newpage

{\Huge B}

\newpage

{\Huge C}

\newpage

{\Huge D}

\newpage

{\Huge E}

\newpage

{\Huge F}

\newpage

{\Huge G}

\newpage

{\Huge H}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to generate and print a booklet using the `pdfpages` package as suggested in [Booklets in memoir class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16967/booklets-in-memoir-class), so my other code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,booklet,landscape]{mytext.pdf}
\end{document}
```

It works perfectly, and my booklet is done, with 2 pages from the original document in each page of the new document. This is the result:

```
   Page 1      |     Page 2       |    Page 3      |     Page 4
  H       A    |    B       G     |   F       C    |    D       E
Page 8  Page 1 |  Page 2  Page 7  | Page 6  Page 3 |  Page 4  Page 5
```

This is the booklet format. So far, so good.

It happens that I should print it by myself, and this format is not good for my needs. So I'd like if the `pdfpages` could insert pages in the following format:

```
   Page 1      |     Page 2       |    Page 3      |     Page 4
  D       A    |    B       C     |   G       D    |    E       F
Page 4  Page 1 |  Page 2  Page 3  | Page 8  Page 5 |  Page 6  Page 7
```

That way, I could print my document in both sides and cut the pages easily:

[image: Pages]

**EDIT:** Other view (pages 2 and 4 are flipped just to explain their position):

[image: Page]

In other words:

[image: Pages]

where `n` is a page number such that `n mod 4 = 1`.

Could also be `[n+2, n], [n+1, n+3]` instead of `[n+3, n], [n+1, n+2]`.

As one mentioned, I could manually specify the page order, but it's not feasible for a document with +100 pages.

Any ideas?

Comment: Personally I would just write a quick shell or Perl script printing the requiered page list. But you can also write a TeX loop to do this. Note that you actually can read out the number of pages in an external PDF using a pdfTeX command, which can then be used as upper limit of the loop. I can't however recall it just now. See the `pdftex` manual.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for the idea, I wrote a Python script and it worked perfectly! Anyway, while trying other options, I found an easier solution with no external tools, may I post that as an answer?

Comment: it's always fine to post an answer yourself. There's some delay before you can accept it though.

Comment: @Alan Thanks! I'll post it. I didn't expect to find an answer by myself. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was unaware of the following option in the `pdfpages` package:

> **signature** Creates booklets by rearranging pages into signatures and setting `nup=1x2` or `nup=2x1`, respectively. This option takes one argument specifying the size of the signature, which should be a multiple of 4.

Right after this paragraph, I could discover that the `booklet` option uses `signature` under the hood:

> **booklet** This option is just a shortcut of the `signature` option, if you choose a signature value so large that all pages fit into one signature. Either `true` or `false` (or no value, which is equivalent to `true`). (Default: `booklet=false`)

So, the solution:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,signature=4,landscape]{mytext.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The output was like I expected. =)

Comment: And I was just starting to code a nice loop for you :-( ;-)

Comment: @Martin: Sorry for spoiling the fun. `=)` I didn't notice that option before. Anyway, I'd love to learn how to code a nice loop for that. `=)`

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the `4 on 2, book format` layout of the [`pgfmorepages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfmorepages) package.  See the documentation for details.